# Relative importance of dummy variables

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding, importance

I would like to identify the relative importance of each predictor variable in a regression model. It's simple enough to do if using just numeric independent variables. The "% influence / relative importance" of each predictor variable would add to 100% so stakeholders can easily understand the output.

However I would like to include a categorical independent variable. I will be converting this categorical variable into binary variables using dummy coding. This means one of the categories will become a reference category and therefore will be a "missing binary variable" in a sense.

Wondering how I identify relative importance of a categorical variable that has been dummy coded?

I was thinking of just adding the relative importance scores of each dummy variable, but this wouldn't include the missing category / missing dummy variable that has become the reference category?